# Pie chart labels get displaced when the chart is published

Tags: charts, label, tableau-api, pie-chart

A Tableau pie chart has automatically-placed slice labels, and looks OK.
However when the dashboard is published (and shows the same data, from the same data source), labels position are displaced and the chart is screwed up - when viewed either in Chrome or IE. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide additional information which can help us reproduce the error that you are encountering. How to create a minimal reproducible error and other important inputs to give while asking a question can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using an Automatic or Fixed sizing?